# I am unable to get value from div tag

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<div id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" contenteditable>100</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please give me some solution on this. In output i get value for x is "undefined".

Comment: `div` tags don't have values.

Answer (score 4):

A div doesn't have a value property like a form input does. You need to get the HTML of the element with:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myInput").innerHTML;
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
```

```html
<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<div id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" contenteditable>100</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a input text field. So, you cannot use value property.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x.innerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers you can change your myInput element to an

<textarea.. or <input type="text"..

```
<textarea id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">100</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<div id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" contenteditable>100</div>
```

To:

```
<input id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is use <**input**> tag :) , and if u don't want the <**input**> tag display on your view so add '**disabled**' attribute into it.
ex:

```
<input type="text" value="your_value" id="your_id" oninput="your_function()" disabled>
```